# Kryonet MiniLog doesn't show anything

Tags: logging, kryonet

I am using Kryonet 2.21 on Windows 8 by using JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA 14. Here is my Problem:

Recently I tried to write a Server Application with Kryonet, but no matter which Log-Level I set, the Log wont show anything...
I hope somebody gets my fault - Here is my Code:

```
public class GServerConManager
{
    private static final int    TCPPORT = 4420;
    private static final int    UDPPORT = 4421;

    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private Server  server    = null;
    private Kryo    kryo      = null;
```

The Constructor of my Object sets the Loglevel to "LEVEL_DEBUG".

```
    public GServerConManager() throws IOException
    {
        Log.set(Log.LEVEL_DEBUG);
        this.server = new Server();
        registerNetClasses();
        this.server.bind(TCPPORT,UDPPORT);
        this.server.addListener(new GServerListener());
    }
```

You see the "public void start()" methode. It performs in the Main methode but "Server started!" never gets printed on my console.

```
    public void start()
    {
        if(!isRunning)
        {
            isRunning = true;
            this.server.start();
            Log.debug("Server started!");
        }
```

No output here too....

```
        else
        {
            Log.debug("Sever is already running!");
        }
    }
```

Same in the "public void stop()" methode.

```
    public void stop()
    {
        if(this.isRunning)
        {
            isRunning = false;
            this.server.stop();

            Log.debug("Server stopped!");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.debug("Server already stoppped!");
        }
    }

    private void registerNetClasses()
    {
        this.kryo = this.server.getKryo();
    }
}
```

The methodes get performed in the Main methode by using a Switch statement.
Sorry if my English isn't the best, I try hard to write my request easy to understand.
Thanks :)